# What an implementation should do in case of operator new and "nested" initialization

Tags: c++

I know that an implementation should free any allocated memory if the constructor of an object throws an exception in situation like this:

```
new T(); // Suppose that T() throws an exception
```

but what about the following code?

```
new T(f()); // Suppose that T() does NOT throw any exception, but f() does
```

What should implementation do in this case? Should it free any allocated memory then?

Comment: The implementation should free any memory that it allocated for the `T` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current C++ standard (C++14, as well as in the previous versions C++11 and C++03), it is unspecified whether memory is allocated before or after `f()` is evaluated, but in any case memory will be freed if it has been allocated; **[expr.new]**:

> 20 - If any part of the object initialization described above<sup>79</sup> terminates by throwing an exception, storage has
>   been obtained for the object, and a suitable deallocation function can be found, the deallocation function is
>   called to free the memory [...]
>
> 79) This may include evaluating a *new-initializer* and/or calling a constructor.

Here the *new-initializer* is `f()`, so if the evaluation of `f()` throws an exception, the deallocation function will be called (if found).

Since C++17, the allocation of memory is sequenced *before* the evaluation of `f()`, so the memory will always be deallocated:

> 21 - If any part of the object initialization described above<sup>79</sup> terminates by throwing an exception and a suitable
>   deallocation function can be found, the deallocation function is called [...]

Note though that since memory allocation is elidable, the implementation is in practice free to omit the allocation if it can predict that an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And what about C++98 / C++03 and C++11?

Comment: @FrozenHeart C++11 and C++03 are the same as C++14.

Comment: Ah, thanks. "it is unspecified whether memory is allocated before or after f() is evaluated" -- I think that the same applies to `T`'s constructor as well?

Comment: @FrozenHeart no, both `f()` and the allocation function have to be complete by the time the constructor of `T` begins - that's because they're required for the initial values of the `this` and the constructor parameter.

Comment: Nah, I mean that it's not guaranteed that an implementation will allocate memory before `T`'s constructor. Am I right?

Comment: @FrozenHeart it has to allocate memory to be able to call the constructor of `T`, because there has to be somewhere for `this` to point to. I'm not sure whether you mean something else, though.

Comment: _"Here the new-initializer is f(), so if the evaluation of f() throws an exception, the deallocation function will be called (if found)."_  : what do you mean by _"the deallocation function will be called"_ ? which is in the OP's example ?

Comment: @shrike OP is using the global `::operator new`, so the corresponding deallocation function is `::operator delete`. But it's possible for there to be no corresponding deallocation function; the most obvious example would be placement-new (new into a preexisting buffer) where there's nothing to deallocate.

Comment: @ecatmur : ok, this actually is what I understood, which though is quite confusing : if the `delete` operator was called, then class `T`'s destructor would be called, am I right ? however, all tests I made show it is not : if `f()` raises an exception, neither `T` ctor nor dtor is called. What am I missing here ?

Comment: @shrike there's a difference between the `delete` operator and `::operator delete`. Writing `delete p` will check that `p` is non-null, call the destructor of `*p`, and then invoke `::operator delete` (or some other `operator delete`) to free memory. Writing `::operator delete(p)` will just free memory.